# Operation has type int32 that does not match type int64

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

I am attempting to train some data using a DNN provided by `tflearn`. My `data` variable has a shape of `(6605, 32)` and my `labels` data has a shape of `(6605,)` which I reshape below to `(6605, 1)`...

```
# Target label used for training
labels = np.array(data[label], dtype=np.float32)

# Reshape target label from (6605,) to (6605, 1)
labels = tf.reshape(labels, shape=[-1, 1])

# Data for training minus the target label.
data = np.array(data.drop(label, axis=1), dtype=np.float32)

# DNN
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 32])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model.
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
```

After running this I get two errors, the first is...

> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for Tensor with dtype int32: 'Tensor("strided_slice/stack_4:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)'

And the second error is...

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError: Input 'strides' of 'StridedSlice' Op has type int32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'begin'.

I can't figure out how to solve the issue. So one approach I took was changing the `dtype` for `labels` and `data` to `int64`...

```
# Target label used for training
labels = np.array(data[label], dtype=np.int64)

# Reshape target label from (6605,) to (6605, 1)
labels = tf.reshape(labels, shape=[-1, 1])

# Data for training minus the target label.
data = np.array(data.drop(label, axis=1), dtype=np.int64)
```

But if I do this I still get the same errors. How can I fix this?

Comment: which version of tensorflow did you upgrade to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems to be generated by an older build of tensorflow. I updated tensorflow by using...

```
pip3 install tensorflow --upgrade
```

This removed the `int64` error. It seems there was an issue casting *long* data types such as `int64` in the older build.

After updating, I get a different error due to the shape of the tensor...

> Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [6605,1], [1,16], [1,16], [1].

But this is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the error states a ValueError regarding integers, int64 and int32, so the conversion at question should be int not float.

I had a similar case in a code base that it was not possible to update tensorflow, 
I was producing an index which  was causing an int type ValueError.

In case upgrading tensorflow's version is not possible, you can cast to int32, like:

**new_var = tf.cast(old_var, tf.int32)**

If you check the exact line the error occurs you should find the culprit, cast it and it should work. This solution should work for both int and float casting (using tf.float32).